# Match two columns of two different data.frames

Tags: r

Sorry guys, but I'm experiencing some troubles with the data I have to manage.
I have two data.frames:

> ```
>   DF1              
> Col1          Col2      Col3     
> Cell_line1    0.11       G1
> Cell_line1a   0.2        G1
> Cell_line2    0.44       G1
> Cell_line2a   0.32       G1
> Cell_line3    0.67       G1
> Cell_line3a   0.98       G1
> Cell_line4    0.55       G1
> Cell_line4a   0.5        G1        
> Cell_line1    0.1        G2
> Cell_line1a   0.22       G2
> Cell_line2    0.47       G2
> Cell_line2a   0.31       G2
> Cell_line3    0.65       G2
> Cell_line3a   0.92       G2
> Cell_line4    0.53       G2
> Cell_line4a   0.7        G2   
> ............................
> ```

Until 640 rows.

Then another data.frame that looks like:

> ```
>   DF1              
> Col1             Col3     
> Cell_line1        G1
> Cell_line1a       G1
> Cell_line3        G2
> Cell_line3a       G2
> Cell_line4        G2
> Cell_line4a       G2
> ```

I would like the following output:

> ```
>   DF3              
> Col1          Col2      Col3     
> Cell_line1    0          G1
> Cell_line1a   0          G1
> Cell_line2    0.44       G1
> Cell_line2a   0.32       G1
> Cell_line3    0.67       G1
> Cell_line3a   0.98       G1
> Cell_line4    0.55       G1
> Cell_line4a   0.5        G1        
> Cell_line1    0.1        G2
> Cell_line1a   0.22       G2
> Cell_line2    0.47       G2
> Cell_line2a   0.31       G2
> Cell_line3    0          G2
> Cell_line3a   0          G2
> Cell_line4    0          G2
> Cell_line4a   0          G2   
> ............................
> ```

In other words I would like to match the first column of DF1 with the first column of DF2 and the third column of DF1 with the second column of DF2 and replace the numerical values in DF1[,2] with 0 where the match occurs. 
Can anyone help me please?
Best

E.

Comment: You know which steps you should take. (I would make this steps in my script in the exact order you said.). What trouble did you find? What did you tried and didn't worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create an index column and use `merge`:

```
DF1$id <- seq_len(nrow(DF1))
DF1[merge(DF1, DF2)$id, "Col2"] <- 0
DF1$id <- NULL
#           Col1 Col2 Col3
# 1   Cell_line1 0.00   G1
# 2  Cell_line1a 0.00   G1
# 3   Cell_line2 0.44   G1
# 4  Cell_line2a 0.32   G1
# 5   Cell_line3 0.67   G1
# 6  Cell_line3a 0.98   G1
# 7   Cell_line4 0.55   G1
# 8  Cell_line4a 0.50   G1
# 9   Cell_line1 0.10   G2
# 10 Cell_line1a 0.22   G2
# 11  Cell_line2 0.47   G2
# 12 Cell_line2a 0.31   G2
# 13  Cell_line3 0.00   G2
# 14 Cell_line3a 0.00   G2
# 15  Cell_line4 0.00   G2
# 16 Cell_line4a 0.00   G2
```